# HTTP/2 request, but push not support

Tags: go, http2

I'm starting to play with go http/2 push, and the examples are not working for me.
The request is in http/2 (I can see "Version: HTTP/2.0" in firefox, and I have an extension to tell if the server is using http/2).
Yet, something like:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if pusher, ok := w.(http.Pusher); ok {
        // Push is supported.
        if err := pusher.Push("/app.js", nil); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Failed to push: %v", err)
        }
    } else {
      fmt.Println("Push not supported")
    }
    // ...
})
```

Always displays "Push not supported".
Any hint to debug that?

Thanks

Comment: If I ignore the assertion, and try to push anyway, I get a Panic: 2017-06-03_01:05:22.85073 Pushing CSS --------------------
2017-06-03_01:05:22.85087 2017/06/03 01:05:22 http2: panic serving 172.18.0.1:43268: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2017-06-03_01:05:22.85088 goroutine 86 [running]:
2017-06-03_01:05:22.85088 net/http.(*http2serverConn).runHandler.func1(0xc42000c038, 0xc42015ffaf, 0xc420133880)
2017-06-03_01:05:22.85090       /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/src/net/http/h2_bundle.go:4604 +0x190

Comment: Ignoring the assertion is guaranteed not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it, it's because I'm using negroni: https://github.com/urfave/negroni/issues/173